# Google WebSearch API custom search throws TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

We have a custom searchbar on our website and I noticed that sometimes (9/10 times) the `JS` will throw this error, which forces the content that you searched for to not render

> www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1gu…oogle.com&callback=google.search.Search.apiary####&nocache=1446053383742:2
>
> Uncaught TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary#### is not a function

**Search page when error is thrown:**
[image: Search page when error is thrown]

**Search page with error truncated/resolved**
[image: Search page when error is truncated or resolved]

But if I were to refresh, or research, this error is trumped and will render all of my searches. After looking through the file, I found out the `google.search.Search.apiary####` that they are referring to is only mentioned once. So I believe that this error is truncating the entire file *when it does show up*. What could be causing this, what would be some options for fixing it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggested solution. As a matter of fact, we are using a simple HTML TEXT box on all our pages and then redirect the search query to a specific search only page.
On this search page, we do have the Google's search box (generated by script) and the search results. I believe, the script that was run twice was causing the issue for us too. I have removed one of them and it seems to work at this time.
Thanks a lot for documenting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I stumbled upon an answer:-

After doing some more research, I found that [this user on Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/CYN9lFK46hk) also has the same issue.

To put it simply, the way it works is you use a `<script>` to generate your searchbar.

**You have this function + html element for your search bar**

```
<script>
 (function() {
   var cx = '###';
   var gcse = document.createElement('script');
   gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
   gcse.async = true;
   gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
       '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
 })();
</script>

<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="/search-results"></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

So we generated the bar in our `<div class="header">` which is a `HAML` element, as a part of a template. So it was always loaded within every header. Since we have 10 pages, this same script was generated 1 time per page.

Our Google CSE is made to search and then redirect to the url `/search-results` where it generates the results.

**To generate the results, you needed this function and HTML**

```
<script>
     (function() {
       var cx = '###';
       var gcse = document.createElement('script');
       gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
       gcse.async = true;
       gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
           '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
     })();
    </script>
```

Which is the same as the one being loaded in our Header.
With this set up, the results page would call that `<script>` twice when loading in, and cause the `JS` to break. So after removing the `<script>` loading the results, it stopped throwing the error.

To put it brief, just make sure you aren't calling the same `function` twice on your results page, and it should clear up the `Uncaught TypeError`.

**Don't. Repeat. Yourself**

--ether

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidentally had [the form and script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14455182/74585) for the Google Custom Search repeated twice on the same page. Once the second lot was removed it stopped giving the error.