# Search button - form action?

Tags: forms, button, search, action

I've read an tutorial to make an search form for your site. This is the code.

```
            <div class="arama">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="kelime" placeholder="Cauta..."/>
                <button type="submit" name="gonder"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

but it did not explain how to make this thing work. I want to make this search button to find anything is on my site. Ex: If i press "A" on search then it will give me on a different page more links.

Like on this website: http://www.dizibox.com/?s=su     (search anything else)

Explain me please how should I do it. I don't want to just copy-paste.

Thank you. ( I think that it's something what implies article title.)

EDIT: I managed to do something with google CSE, but it's on their own layout, not mine. Question is still avaible. Thank you

EDIT2: RESOLVED. ANSWER HERE: [Google Custom Search (CSEv2) help on styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103263/google-custom-search-csev2-help-on-styling)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. There are different languages you can use to achieve this. If jQuery is acceptable, I would recommend something like http://www.tipue.com/search/

Comment: I want to use google CSE. It gives me the code : <gcse:search></gcse:search>   


But I want to make this to be on my searchbar.


Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174187/google-custom-search-with-custom-search-box-and-button

Comment: @NickyTheWrench I was looking over it. The issue is that it gives me their searchbox. I want to use mine.

Comment: I figured id out, thanks.